# É possível programar em Javascript no Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

pergunta básica, mas específica:

Em uma vídeo aula pediram pra baixar o **VS Code** e o **Node.js** pra começar a programar em Javascript

Como eu tenho o **Visual Studio Community 2017** instalado, eu consigo acompanhar as aulas usando essa IDE (pois parece bem *completa*)? Ou vou precisar do VS Code mesmo?

Comment: Você está _matando a formiga com a bazuca_. Acho que dificilmente o Visual Studio fornecerá ferramentas melhores se comparados ao VSCode. Penso, inclusive, que seja pior, já que a IDE é significativamente mais pesada. Em suma, se eu fosse você, eu usaria o VSCode, que é ideal para programar em JS. :)

Comment: O VS é sem dúvida mais pesado, mas eu já o tenho instalado. :(

Comment: Ninguem lhe impede de instalar mais de uma aplicação no seu pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim, inclusive existem alguns videos na internet falando sobre o Javascript no Visual Studio 2017

[Vídeo programando no Visual Studio 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXseZj7bHsg)

Porém caso você não tenha muita experiência com a linguagem pode ser que tenha mais dificuldade para acompanhar as vídeo aulas, mas creio ser questão de costume mesmo.